# Android code to save data in sqlite when no internet connection

Tags: android, android-sqlite, offline

Hi i made a small application where i need to store data in sqlite when no internet connection. this is my code. It is not showing any error but data is not saving in sqlite. What is the problem.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(isOnline()==true)
                {
                    if(edittext1.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Key NO(FX)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(edittext2.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Old switch MAC ID(Volktek)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(switchtypedata.contains("New Switch Type"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select New Switch Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(edittext3.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter CTS Switch IP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(batteryreplaceddata.contains("Fx Battery Replaced"))    
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Fx Battery Replaced or Not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(batterytype.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        if(batterytypedata.contains("Battery Type"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Battery Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(edittext4.getText().toString().length()==0)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Replaced Battery serial No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(edittext5.getText().toString().length()==0)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Recovered Battery Serial No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            ed1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
                            ed2 = edittext2.getText().toString();
                            ed3 = edittext3.getText().toString();
                            ed4 = edittext4.getText().toString();
                            ed5 = edittext5.getText().toString();
                            ed6 = edittext6.getText().toString();
                            ed7 = edittext7.getText().toString();

                            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(FXPage.this, "", 
                                    "Validating user...", true);
                             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        login();                          
                                    }
                                  }).start();  
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ed1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
                        ed2 = edittext2.getText().toString();
                        ed3 = edittext3.getText().toString();
                        ed4 = edittext4.getText().toString();
                        ed5 = edittext5.getText().toString();
                        ed6 = edittext6.getText().toString();
                        ed7 = edittext7.getText().toString();

                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(FXPage.this, "", 
                                "Validating user...", true);
                         new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    login();                          
                                }
                              }).start();  
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ed1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
                    ed2 = edittext2.getText().toString();
                    ed3 = edittext3.getText().toString();
                    ed4 = edittext4.getText().toString();
                    ed5 = edittext5.getText().toString();
                    ed6 = edittext6.getText().toString();
                    ed7 = edittext7.getText().toString();

                    System.out.println("benarjee"+ed1+ed2+ed3+ed4+ed5+ed6+ed7);

                    myDatabaseHelper =new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
                    sqLiteDatabase= myDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    MyDatabaseHelper.addinnformation(username,ed1,ed2,switchtypedata,ed3,batteryreplaceddata,batterytypedata,ed4,ed5,ed6,ed7,sqLiteDatabase);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    myDatabaseHelper.close();
                    System.out.println("print this");

                }


                }
        });
```

---

sqlite code:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     private static final String DATABASE_NAME="NUP.DB";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

        private static final String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+ FXInfo.FXDetails.TABLE_NAME+"("+
                FXInfo.FXDetails.USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+ FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_KEYNO+" TEXT, "
                + FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_OLDSWITCHMACID+" TEXT, "+ FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_NEWSWITCHTYPE+" TEXT, "
                + FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_CTSSWITCHIP+" TEXT, "+ FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_BATTREYREPLACED+" TEXT, "
                + FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_BATTREYTYPE+" TEXT, "+ FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_REPLACEDBATTERYSERIALNO+" TEXT, "
                + FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_RECOVERDBATTERYSERIALNO+" TEXT, "+ FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_GPSCOORDINATES+" TEXT, "
                + FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_FEEDBACK+" TEXT );";



    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
            Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "Table create..."+CREATE_QUERY);

            System.out.println("call this");
    }

     public static void addinnformation(String name,String fxkeyno,String fxoldswitchmacid,String fxnewswitchtype,
            String ctsswitchip, String fxbatteryreplaced,String fxbattertype,String fxbatteryreplacedsrialno,
            String fxbatteryrecoveredserialno,String fxgpscoordinates, String fxfeedback, SQLiteDatabase db){

         ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.USER_NAME,name);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_KEYNO,fxkeyno);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_OLDSWITCHMACID,fxoldswitchmacid);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_NEWSWITCHTYPE,fxnewswitchtype);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_CTSSWITCHIP,ctsswitchip);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_BATTREYREPLACED,fxbatteryreplaced);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_BATTREYTYPE,fxbattertype);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_REPLACEDBATTERYSERIALNO,fxbatteryreplacedsrialno);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_RECOVERDBATTERYSERIALNO,fxbatteryrecoveredserialno);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_GPSCOORDINATES,fxgpscoordinates);
            contentValue.put(FXInfo.FXDetails.FX_FEEDBACK,fxfeedback);
            db.insert(FXInfo.FXDetails.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValue);
            Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "One row is insert");
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------DOA class:

```
public static abstract class FXDetails
    {
     public static final String USER_NAME="user_name";
     public static final String TABLE_NAME="fxinfor";
        public static final String FX_KEYNO="fxkeyno";
        public static final String FX_OLDSWITCHMACID="fxoldswitchmacid";
        public static final String FX_NEWSWITCHTYPE="fxnewswitchmacid";
        public static final String FX_CTSSWITCHIP = "fxctsswitchip";
        public static final String FX_BATTREYREPLACED = "fxbatteryreplaced";
        public static final String FX_BATTREYTYPE = "fxbatterytype";
        public static final String FX_REPLACEDBATTERYSERIALNO = "fxreplacedbatteryserialno";
        public static final String FX_RECOVERDBATTERYSERIALNO = "fxbatteryrecoveredserialno";
        public static final String FX_GPSCOORDINATES = "fxcoordinates";
        public static final String FX_FEEDBACK = "fxfeedback";
    }
```

Comment: can i know how are you checking the internet connection ? as that is one major thing ... and why cant you create a manager which handles which request to execute and which request to keep in database !!

Comment: Here you can find a great tutorial on using SQLite database in android. http://www.startingandroid.com/how-to-use-sqlite-database-in-android/